# Prevent crystal report skipping some data in the first row

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, datatable, datagridview, crystal-reports

```
    Using con as sqlconnection=sqlcon() 


     Dim cmd as new sqlcommand("select * from exams", con) 
     Con.open
     Dr = cmd.executereader()
     Dim da as new sqldataadapter(cmd) 
     Dim dt as new datatable("exams" ) 
     Dt.Load(dr) 
     Dgvexam.Datasource = dt
     Dr.Close
     Showgrades() 
     Con.Close() 

     Dim report as new CrystalreportExam
     Report.Setdatasource(dt) 
     Examviewer.Examview.Reportsource=report
     Examviewer.Show
    End using
End sub
```

The datagridview is filling all the rows correctly. When the crystal report loads, the first row contains marks only, the grades are missing.
But from row 2 downwards there's no problem. Data is loading well.